# Posting data from a form into the database using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to have a user input a task from the frontend and have that data instantiate a new model and add this new field in the database associated with their account. I have tried the following;

## Profile HTML

```
<form id="taskitem_form" method="post" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Task" class ="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

## Model

```
class TaskItem(models.Model):
    taskn = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    usern = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.taskn
```

## Views

```
  def add_task(request):
        # Get the context from the request.
        #context = RequestContext(request)

    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskItemForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.save(commit=False)
            task.usern = request.user
            task.save()
    # we should redirect after data modifying
            return redirect('/user/%s' %(request.user))
        else:
            # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

## Forms

```
from django import forms
from bkmks.models import TaskItem

class TaskItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    taskn = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, help_text = "Please enter your task")

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        fields = ('taskn', 'usern' )
        #This is the association between the model and the model form
        model = TaskItem
```

Comment: TaskItemForm shows only `taskn` in the fields parameter. What about the `usern` field? You should set it yourself in the form validation.

Comment: You haven't stated what the problem is. One obvious issue, which is nothing to do with forms, is that you haven't specified the template in your render_to_response calls (it should be the first parameter, for some reason you have a / there instead).

Comment: There isn't a text box visible on my html page whatsoever. The goal of adding '/' was for no redirect to happen or redirect to the main page. I was more just testing this to see if the data could be entered and shown up in the database.

Comment: Redirect and render are completely different things. The code as you have posted it would produce an error because the first param must be a template name. Please post the *actual* code.

Comment: return render_to_response("profile.html",  {'form': form,  }, context_instance = RequestContext(request)) would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lot's of Changes needed to your code.

I'm posting a working version so that you can try.

Put profile.html file as bkmks/templates/bkmks/profile.html

Get it working. Customize later.

#### profile.html

```
<form id="taskitem_form" method="post" action="">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Task" class ="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

model as it is.

#### views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext, redirect
from .forms import TaskItemForm

@login_required
def add_task(request):
    # Get the context from the request.
    context = RequestContext(request)

    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskItemForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            task = form.save(commit=False)
            task.usern = request.user
            task.save()


            # Redirect to home (/)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = TaskItemForm()

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render_to_response('bkmks/profile.html', {'form': form}, context)
```

#### forms.py

```
class TaskItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # task is changed to taskn
    taskn = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, help_text = "Please enter your task")

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        fields = ('taskn',)
        #This is the association between the model and the model form
        model = TaskItem
```

If you get any error or data is not getting saved post here.

Going through Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/) will be an wise decision.

Comment: No errors, but the form isn't showing on the html page.

Comment: Check update. Missed `from .forms import TaskItemForm` earlier.

Comment: Same issue still unfortunately

Comment: What's your profile.html path/location and Template settings in settings.py?

Comment: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates') for the template directory. Directly inside of that exists profile.html which I have changed to just profile.html in your code that you provided.

Comment: return render_to_response('profile.html', {'form': form}, context)

Comment: profile.html is inside templates directory and profile.html is same as posted here?

Comment: Posted the same as what shows above. Is that incorrect?
return render_to_response('profile.html', {'form': form}, context)

Comment: No, that is not incorrect. Are you trying the code I posted above?

Comment: Yes, it's in my code identically and still not getting any visible form posted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78050/discussion-between-ryan-and-moonstruck).

Answer (score 1):

The below should do what you need. You really want to inherit 100% of everything from your model when you can. This insures all model validation trickles down to the form. I utilized `verbose_name` and `help_text` on the model to achieve this.

## Models

```
from django.conf import settings

class TaskItem(models.Model):
    taskn = models.CharField(
        max_length=400,
        verbose_name="task",
        help_text="Please enter your task.",
    )
    usern = models.ForeignKey(
        to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
        related_name="tasks",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.taskn
```

For the forms, I have added a `forms.HiddenInput` widget to the user, assuming you want the user submitting the task to become the user.

## Forms

```
from django import forms
from bkmks.models import TaskItem

class TaskItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    widgets = {
        'user': forms.HiddenInput,
    }

    class Meta:
        model = TaskItem
        fields = ('taskn', 'usern')
```

I have used a `CreateView` to reduce code complexity, and overrode the `form_valid` to add the user instance to the form.

## Views

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from bkmks.models import TaskItem
from bkmks.forms import TaskItemForm

class TaskCreateView(CreateView):
    model = TaskItem
    form_class = TaskItemForm
    template_name = "path/to/template.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(TaskCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Finally, in the template, we simply want to use `{{ form }}`. I see you are looking into bootstrap. I'll suggest [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this, but that is beyond the scope of your question.

## Template

```
<form id="taskitem_form" method="post" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Task" class ="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Getting an error: 'User' object has no attribute 'taskitem_set'

Comment: Did you add `related_name="tasks"` to the `usern` ForeignKey in the `TaskItem` model?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

render_to_response expects a template as the first argument, not a url.

I think in your second call to render_to_response should include the template name / path , while the first one should use a return HttpResponseRedirect("/") instead, though its not clear exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to imports in **views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
```

Decorate `add_task` view

```
@login_required
def add_task(request):
```

Then, edit part of your code

```
if form.is_valid():
    task = form.save(commit=False)
    task.usern = request.user
    task.save()
    # we should redirect after data modifying
    return redirect('/')
else:
    # etc.
```

Some notes. You may replace `render_to_response` to `render`.

Remove this line

```
context = RequestContext(request)
```

Replace

```
# Wrong usage, actually.
# Should be something like
# render_to_response(template_name, context, context_instance)
render_to_respone('/', {'form': form}, context)
```

with

```
# if template_name is "profile.html"
render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I have made the changes, but form is still not showing for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Why define a field called `task` in the form if you've already got a field in the model called `taskn`, wouldn't it be better to just use that? And like the guys have said, you need to specify a template to render (that's why you're not seeing anything).

It'd also be a good idea to pass the current user to the form's user field.

```
@login_required
def add_task(request):
    # Get the context from the request.
    context = {}

    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskItemForm(request.POST)

        # Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            # Save the new category to the database.
            form.save()

            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the homepage.
            return render_to_response(
                'profile.html',
                {'form': form},
                RequestContext(request, context)
            )
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal.
            print form.errors
    else:
        # If the request was not a POST, display the form to enter details.
        form = TaskItemForm(initial={'usern': request.user})

    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error messages (if any).
    return render_to_response(
        'profile.html',
        {'form': form},
        RequestContext(
            request, context
        )
    )
```

Form;

```
from django import forms
from bkmks.models import TaskItem

class TaskItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    taskn = forms.CharField(max_length = 300, help_text = "Please enter your task")

    # An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        fields = ('taskn', 'usern' )
        #This is the association between the model and the model form
        model = TaskItem
```

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions. I have made the change, but still not seeing any visible from on my page. How should I call it in my profile template?

Comment: Oh hang on, the rest of your `render_to_response` is wrong. You need to pass the form in the context. Check the docs link that @wobbily_col has posted & I'll edit this.

Comment: @ryan yeah you need to pass the template as the first arg and then request is passed to `RequestContext()` along with your context dictionary. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: i've literally copied your code into mine, but still can't get this textbox field to show up on the page.